# View variable value in Release Mode - UWP - Windows 10

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to figure out what's going on with my UWP app when I'm trying to display an `InterstitialAd` advert. I want to display it after using the app after two minutes and then every 5 minutes thereafter when something is actioned in my app. It's working as expected in debug mode but not in release mode, so I'm trying to debug my code in release mode to see what's going on but I can't see I can't see the value of the variables.

The code I have in my app.xaml.cs is quite straight forward:

```
public static void VideoAdvertCheck()
{
    if (!IsCoreFeaturesLocked || AdRequested)
        return;

    double elaspedTime;
    bool valid;

    Debug.WriteLine("Elapsed Time since last advert: {0}", 
            DateTime.Now.Subtract(AdvertTimeStart).TotalMinutes);

#if DEBUG
    elaspedTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(AdvertTimeStart).TotalMinutes;
    valid = elaspedTime >= (AdNeverDisplayed ? 1 : 1);
#else
    elaspedTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(AdvertTimeStart).TotalMinutes;
    valid = elaspedTime >= (AdNeverDisplayed ? 2 : 5);
#endif

    if (AdNeverDisplayed && valid)
        AdNeverDisplayed = false;

    //2 minute or 5 minutes has elapsed.
    if (valid)
    {
        RequestVideoAdvert();
    }
}
```

The `elapsedTime` and `valid` variables were both declared within the conditional compile statements and I moved them out hoping it would help but to no avail.

The `valid` always appears to be true even though 2 minutes hasn't elapsed so why it true in the first place and why can't evaluate my variables and/or conditions such as

```
valid = elaspedTime >= (AdNeverDisplayed ? 2 : 5);
```

`AdNeverDisplayed` is set to true when my app is launched.

Can anyone see anything wrong in this logic but more importantly how can I debug this in release mode.

Note that the problems occurs in release mode (on laptop) and when my app is released in the store and downloaded directly on my phone.

I assume this problem is not specific to just universal app as it is pretty generic code.

One thing I noticed is that when in release mode and an InterstitialAd is requested, it triggers the `Cancelled` even. Makes no sense!

**UPDATE - 1:**

I should have mentioned that it stops on the breakpoints when they are set but I cannot see any variables in `Locals`, `Autos` or `Watch`.

Answer (score 0):

For release mode, debug functions are disabled. You need to create extra UI to display value on the screen to you.

Comment: Does that include viewing variables? I've managed to view the content of my local variables by temporarily making them static & global scope to the class, but I noticed that when stepping through the code, it's actually not jumping to the correct lines of code making it look like it's stepping into the "if (valid)" when it's not actually executing the code. I've logged another bug regarding the Interstitial Ads as it looks like it's a bug but no one has got back to me yet. Contact MS as well and they told me to log it in their forum which I will do.

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, there are some differences between Debug and Release compile configuration:

> When you build and run in “Debug” configuration, you are running IL code against the CoreCLR packaged within your application. The .NET system assemblies are packaged alongside your application code, and your application takes a dependency on the Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime (CoreCLR) package.
>
> This means you get the best development experience possible – fast compilation and deployment, rich debugging and diagnostics, and all of the other tools you are accustomed to with .NET development.
>
> When you switch to “Release” mode, by default your app utilizes the .NET Native toolchain. Since the package is compiled to native binaries, the package does not need to contain the .NET framework libraries. In addition, the package is dependent on the latest installed .NET Native runtime as opposed to the CoreCLR package. The .NET Native runtime on the device will always be compatible with your application package.

Another important difference is:

> Release configurations by default optimize the code which loses some artifacts used for debugging. As a result, trying to debug a Release configuration can result in some issues. What you can do instead is to create a custom configuration and enable the .NET Native toolchain for that configuration. Make sure to not optimize code. More details about this can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/29/debugging-net-native-windows-universal-apps.aspx).

For more info, please see: [.NET Native – What it means for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) developers](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/).

So you can refer to [Debugging .NET Native Windows Universal Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/29/debugging-net-native-windows-universal-apps.aspx) to debug your code in "release mode".

If this still can't help you. You may try to use log system/library to log the value of the variables you want to see.